# Lenovo Thinkpad W520 cpufreq frequency scaling not working

Tags: 11.04, thinkpad, cpufreq

For some reason my processor always seems to run on full speed even if I don't do anything. Looking through the web, I've found quite some suggestions.
According to http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling I should be able to list my current governors.

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors: No such file or directory
```

But I cannot since `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq` is not existing on my computer.

I have installed cpufreqd cpufrequtils and libcpufreq0, but because of the missing directory, I get

```
# /etc/init.d/cpufreqd start
* Starting CPU Frequency daemon cpufreqd                                [fail]
```

According to http://changelog.complete.org/archives/572-saving-power-with-cpu-frequency-scaling I should load one of the available modules.

```
# ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/arch/*/kernel/cpu/cpufreq
p4-clockmod.ko  pcc-cpufreq.ko  speedstep-lib.ko
```

The only one that does not result in an error is the speedstep-lib.

```
# modprobe speedstep-lib
```

Any idea what I can do?

```
# lsmod |grep cpu
# lsmod |grep freq
# lsmod |grep acpi
thinkpad_acpi          81587  0 
nvram                  14419  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd                    67382  14 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device
```

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2720QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 2192.750
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov 
pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm c
onstant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf
 pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1
 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tp
r_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4385.50
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

```
# cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 4:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 5:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 6:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 7:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ralf - I cant answer your specific question - but there is a [long thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1780703) on ubuntu forums with various experiences encountered with your laptop

One particular interesting post#8 was acpi issues with your BIOS - possibly you need to use v1.22.

Later on there it mentions a recently released bios version 1.26 that could also resolve acpi issues.

Others mention you should stay clear of 64bit Ubuntu unless you are prepared to install kernel 3.0rc or kernel 2.6.39.